# Is there alternative code for str.contains for one value instead of the series?

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I have one columns with name and surname like:

```
df['clients'] = ['Mike Thompson', 'Anna Frank']
```

And I have separetaly name and the surname of the clients but it is not always correct.

```
df['name'] = ['Mike', 'Joanna']
df['surname'] = ['Thompson', 'Brown']
```

I want to find rows which is not correctly entered the info about clients name and surname. And I have used this code

```
df['clients'][0].str.contains(df.name[0] | df.surname[0], nan=False, regex = True
```

It is not working. I have read that **str.contains()** works for the series not for the one value. Is there any alternative for the str.contains() for only one values not for the series?

Comment: kindly post sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by an incorrect info

Answer (score 0):

Pure string operation

```py
any(x in df['clients'][0] for x in [df.name[0], df.surname[0]]):
```

Or with regex

```py
import re

bool(re.search('|'.join([df.name[0], df.surname[0]]), df['clients'][0]))
```